# Reading data from serial port and save to text file in java

Tags: java, io, serial-port, text-files

I have a jFrame where data is shown from weightscale(connected by SerialPort)...Now I want that the data which's showing on frame should be save like(Text File) in memory ...What should I do
here my code

```
package reporting;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortEvent;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPortPacketListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ShowWeight {

  OutputStream outputstream1;
  PreparedStatement ps1, ps2;
  DefaultTableModel tableModel;

  ResultSet rs1, rs2;
  OraclePreparedStatement ops = null;
  OracleResultSet ors = null, ors2 = null;
  JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
  Connection conn = null;
  CallableStatement stmt = null;
  String[] columnNames;
  JButton button;
  int counter;
  int ctnto;
  String s = null;

  String y = null;
  char a = 0;
  SerialPort ubxPort;
  static JLabel wt1;

  static public void one() {
    System.out.println("static method");
    ShowWeight m = new ShowWeight();
    m.get_record();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Label Example");
    wt1 = new JLabel("First Label.");
    wt1.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 30);
    f.add(wt1);
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    wt1.setText("weight scale working");
    one();

  }

  private final class PacketListener implements SerialPortPacketListener {
    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() {
      return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;
    }
    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
      byte[] newData = event.getReceivedData();

      for (int i = 0; i < newData.length; ++i) {
        a = (char) newData[i];

        if ((!String.valueOf(a).equals("S") && !String.valueOf(a).equals("U")) && i == 0) {
          break;

        } else {
          if (String.valueOf(a).equals("k")) {

            break;

          } else {

            s = String.valueOf(a).replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]", "");
            System.out.print(s);

            y = y + s;

          }

        }
      }

      if (y == "") {
        return;
      } else

      {

        wt1.setText(y);
        outputstream1 = ubxPort.getOutputStream();
        String datatosend = "";
        try {

          outputstream1.write(datatosend.getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }

      }

      y = "";
    }
    public int getPacketSize() {
      return 50;
    }

  }

  public void get_record() {

    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    System.out.println("\nAvailable Ports:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println("   [" + i + "] " + ports[i].getSystemPortName() + ": " + ports[i].getDescriptivePortName() + " - " + ports[i].getPortDescription());

      String serialPortDescriptor = ports[i].getSystemPortName();

      System.err.println(ports[i].getSystemPortName());
      ubxPort = SerialPort.getCommPort(serialPortDescriptor);
      boolean openedSuccessfully = ubxPort.openPort();
      System.out.println("\nOpening " + ubxPort.getSystemPortName() + ": " + ubxPort.getDescriptivePortName() + " - " + ubxPort.getPortDescription() + ": " + openedSuccessfully);
      if (!openedSuccessfully)
        continue;
      System.out.println("Setting read timeout mode to non-blocking");
      ubxPort.setBaudRate(9600);
      ubxPort.removeDataListener();
      System.out.println("\nNow listening for full 100-byte data packets\n");
      PacketListener listener = new PacketListener();
      ubxPort.addDataListener(listener);
    }
  }

}
```

What Should I do for saving data(values)... I have Searched and Googled a lot but did not get any result

Comment: Can you achieve the stated task from a command-line based tool (with no GUI)? Get that working first. The problem (at this stage) has nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: Why not save the data to a table in the Oracle Database instead of a text file?

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) `wt1.setText(y);` write `y` to file. Incidentally though you might get away with it, `if (y == "")` is wrong. Strings are compare in Java with `String.equals` or you could use its length

Comment: @DevilsHnd I want to Save data in memory like we save by filewriter ...Is there any way to write the data of weight instance in e.g abc.txt file??

Comment: @g00se I tried but get only  First value of  "wt1"...I want that for example 10 time weight is measured ...value also be saved in filewriter 10 time not once only

Comment: @DevilsHnd   for example I want to add every instance value into database how can I do it

Comment: You'd need to open the file in *append* mode if you don't want it overwritten